# Why am I getting a ActionView::Template::Error (Nil location provided. Can't build URI) error in Heroku but not in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm building a simple app that consumes the Open Weather Map API and returns some weather parameters and a gif that corresponds to the current weather. Users are able to search for a city's current weather.

Everything is working fine locally but I've deployed to Heroku and when I search for a city it throws an error. The Heroku logs show `ActionView::Template::Error (Nil location provided. Can't build URI` My code is below.

The error occurs on this line: `<div class="gif-container"><%= image_tag(find_gif_url, class: "gif") %>`

views/current_weather.html.erb

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <h1 class="title">The weather in GIFs</h1>

  <div class="search">
    <%= form_tag(current_weather_forecasts_path, method: :get) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, placeholder: "Enter a city", class: "search-field" %>
      <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "search-button" do %>
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% if @forecasts_facade.invalid_city? %>
    <p>Please use a valid city name!</p>
  <% elsif @forecasts_facade.missing_city? %>
    <p>Please type in a city name!</p>
  <% elsif @forecasts_facade.forecast == {} %>
  <% else %>
    <p class="weather-description"><%= "#{@city.capitalize}: #{@forecasts_facade.description}" %></p>
    <div class="gif-container"><%= image_tag(find_gif_url, class: "gif") %>
      <span class="temperature weather-attribute"><%= "#{@forecasts_facade.temperature}°C" %></span>
      <span class="wind weather-attribute"><%= "wind:#{(@forecasts_facade.wind * 3.6).to_i}km/h" %></span> <!-- converts to km/hr -->
      <span class="humidity weather-attribute"><%= "humidity:#{@forecasts_facade.humidity}%" %></span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

forecasts_controller.rb

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController

  TOKEN = Rails.application.credentials.openweather_key

  def current_weather
    @city = params[:q]
    if @city.nil?
      @forecast = {}
    else
      @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@city, TOKEN).my_location_forecast
    end
    @forecasts_facade = ForecastsFacade.new(@forecast)
  end
end
```

helpers/forecasts_helper.rb

```
module ForecastsHelper
  GIFS = {
    thunder:
      {codes: [200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 221, 230, 231, 232],
       urls: %w(
          https://media.giphy.com/media/26uf5HjasTtxtNCqQ/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/vS09bj1KrXwje/giphy.gif
)},
    light_rain:
      {codes: [300, 301, 302, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 321, 500, 501, 520, 521],
       urls: %w(
          https://media.giphy.com/media/xT9GEz2CeU9uaI2KZi/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/k28n1OPefBEeQ/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/H1eu9Vw957Rfi/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/Jyeo8wBpdwpry/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/14d8cRr25KPxbG/giphy.gif
)},
    heavy_rain:
      {codes: [502, 503, 504, 522, 531, 511],
       urls: %w(
          https://media.giphy.com/media/1Yfxps0AHRYBR2tK2G/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/7zSIC0roM238CVTS4u/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/l0Expn6D0D3g9NExq/giphy.gif
)},
    }

  def find_gif_url
    GIFS.each do |key, value|
      if value[:codes].include? @forecasts_facade.weather_code
        return value[:urls].sample
      end
    end
  end
end
```

facades/forecasts_facade.rb

```
class ForecastsFacade

  attr_accessor *%w(
    forecast
  ).freeze

  def initialize(forecast)
    @forecast = forecast
  end

  def temperature
    @temperature = forecast.dig('main', 'temp').to_i - 273
  end

  def weather_code
    @weather_code = forecast.dig('weather', 0, 'id').to_i
  end

  def description
    @description = forecast.dig('weather', 0, 'description')
  end

  def wind
    @wind = forecast.dig('wind', 'speed').to_i
  end

  def humidity
    @humidity = forecast.dig('main', 'humidity')
  end

  def invalid_city?
    forecast.dig('cod').to_i == 404 
  end

  def missing_city?
    forecast.dig('cod').to_i == 400
  end

end
```

services/open_weather_api.rb

```
class OpenWeatherApi
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://api.openweathermap.org"

  def initialize(city, appid)
    @options = { query: { q: city, APPID: appid } }
  end

  def my_location_forecast
    self.class.get("/data/2.5/weather", @options)
  end
end
```

Comment: A Ruby error message usually includes the exact file name and line number in which the error occurred. Please add that information. Furthermore, you check that `@city.nil?`, what happens if `@city` is an empty string? You might want to check `.blank?` instead. Is `TOKEN` set in your `production` environment?

Comment: @spickermann I've added the line of code where the error happens to the question. `TOKEN` is set in the encrypted credentials file.

Comment: What is `find_gif_url`? Where and how is it defined?

Comment: @spickermann it is defined in a helper class. I've added the file code to the question now.

Comment: It feels to me like `@forecasts_facade.weather_code` is returning an unexpected code – perhaps the list of code is not complete, or it might be blank in certain cases. Did you check what code is actually returned? Furthermore, I suggest having a fallback icon just in case.

Comment: @spickermann if it was returning an unexpected code it would presumably do that in development too, but it is working fine in development. How do I check which code is returned from the external API?

Comment: You could log the returned value to your logfile in that method before the actual error occurs. Something like `Rails.logger.info("WEATHER CODE: #{@forecasts_facade.weather_code.inspect}")` should work.

Comment: @spickermann Hmmm, I'm not really sure how to do that, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @Steve Try adding a error monitor, something like airbrake https://elements.heroku.com/addons/airbrake - it will help you see the stack trace and you will be able to better rule out the issue. `find_gif_url` is definitely returning nil, you might want to put a check for nil return in `find_gif_url` method and return a default value instead of nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to this method:

```rb
def find_gif_url
  GIFS.each do |key, value|
    if value[:codes].include? @forecasts_facade.weather_code
      return value[:urls].sample
    end
  end
end
```

Is returning `nil`. That is to say that your search for an entry in the `GIFS` hash did not actually find a result. Consider the value of `@forecasts_facade.weather_code` and why it might not be found in the value of `value[:codes]`. Adding some code to handle the case where an entry in `GIFS` was not found is probably a good idea.

As an aside, I might recommend using [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) instead of iterating over `GIFS` and returning manually. That would be "idiomatic Ruby", or the "Ruby way to do it".

Comment: why would it be working fine in development and not in production?

Comment: @Steve I don't know enough about your application be able to give you an answer to that question beyond guessing. At first glance I'd check whether `TOKEN` is being set in production properly. `ForecastsFacade` is a complete black box to everyone here as well, and we don't know how it would handle a token value of `nil`. We just have no way of knowing what the possible values of `@forecast_facade` are, and the reason you're encountering the problem is beacuse the if statement condition (`if value[:codes].include? @forecasts_facade.weather_code`) is never true for any of the values in `GIFS`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Not sure how I missed it. I've added my service class and facade to give you more of an idea about the application. At the moment `TOKEN` is being set in my encrypted credentials file. It is not set specifically for development or production - just as one key `openweather_key`